# Why am I getting "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" when reading radio button values from an MS Word doc?

Tags: vba, ms-word, radio-button, activex

I wrote a program that reads Microsoft Word Content Control and ActiveX field data and inserts it into a database. It runs great on my system. However, in testing I got "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" error. I was able to determine that it was radio buttons (ActiveX objects) that are the culprit. I created the following test script for radio buttons only. Here is the code:

```
Sub GetRBData()

Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim sql As String
Dim Fields As String
Dim Values As String

For Each shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With shp
        If .Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject And .OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
            With .OLEFormat.Object
                Fields = Fields & .GroupName & ", "
                Values = Values & "'" & Right(.Name, Len(.Name) - Len(.GroupName)) & "', "
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next shp

Fields = Left(Fields, Len(Fields) - 2)
Values = Left(Values, Len(Values) - 2)

sql = sql & "INSERT INTO MYTABLE " & "(" & Fields & ")" & " VALUES " & "(" & Values & ")"

MsgBox sql

End Sub
```

I thought maybe the issue is with Microsoft Object Libraries. I checked both. Both are using Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment...

```
If .Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject And .OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
```

If the first test fails then the second test is still evaluated, which would be a problem if the shape is of a type which has no `.OLEFormat.Object`

You should nest the tests:

```
If .Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
    If .OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
```